# Solvability, nilpotence and permutation Groups

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, solvable-groups, nilpotent-groups

I had tried some questions in Group Theory in January but Could not post the questions on which I am struck because of my illness. So, I am writing them now. I have done a graduate level course on group theory.

> Prove that $S_n$ is solvable for $n\leq4$, but $S_3$ and $S_4$ are not nilpotent.

It is trivial for $n \leq 2$. If I use the definition of derived subgroup for $n=3$, $n=4$ and proving $G'_n=\langle e\rangle$,  then it will be a brute force method and I don't feel like doing it. So, I am looking for some elegent way.

Also, I am at loss of ideas on how to prove that $S_3$ and $S_4$ are not nilpotent. Actually, It is my weak point. So, can you also give some hint for this.
Thanks!

Comment: What is your definition of a nilpotent group? Do you know any equivalent definition for a solvable group?

Comment: A few possibilities that spring to mind (depending on what else you have learned). Brute force. Undoubtely you can crank out enough commutators to see that $[S_3,S_3]=A_3$ and $[S_4,S_4]=A_4$. Continue along the same lines and show that $[A_3,S_3]=A_3$ and $[A_4,S_4]=A_4$. Non-nilpotency follows from this. Alternatively, if you have seen a proof for the fact that nilpotent groups are direct products of their Sylow subgroups, or have normal Sylow subgroups, then using that instead is a lot simpler.

Comment: You say "it will be a brute force method and I don't feel like doing it". Well, $S_3$ has only $6$ elements, so won't take particularly long to do. I suggest doing the brute force here, so you get a feel for how it works and see if it gives you any insight into $S_4$, or helps you spot a more elegant way. Boring calculations like these can help you spot patterns and understand things better. They're good for the soul.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A nilpotent group has a nontrivial center, and the center of group $S_3$ (and $S_4$) is trivial.

Comment: Can you also help in proving how $S_n$ is solvable for $n\leq 4$

Comment: These questions are answered by @JyrkiLahtonen, see his comment above.
The groups $S_3$ and $S_4$ are solvable since $S_3>A_3>1$
and $S_4>A_4>V_4>1$
are subnormal series whose quotient groups are all abelian for $S_3$ and $S_4$, respectively.
Here $V_4=\{1,(12)(34),(13)(24),(14)(23)\}$ is  the Klein four-group.